# Delphi: how to retrieve all items of a listview (WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.74db74_r6_ad1) from a C# (.NET) application?

Tags: c#, listview, delphi

I have the following code written in Delphi (using Delphi 10.1 Berlin) and which works fine when trying to retrieve all items of a listview (SysListView32) from another program written in C++.

However, the same code does not work for listviews in .NET applications (a C# program in this instance):

```
function ListViewColumnCount(mHandle: THandle): Integer;
begin
   Result := Header_GetItemCount(ListView_GetHeader(mHandle));
end;

function GetListViewText(mHandle: THandle; mStrings: TStrings): Boolean;
var
  vColumnCount: Integer;
  vItemCount: Integer;
  I, J: Integer;
  vBuffer: array[0..255] of Char;
  vPRocessId: DWord;
  vProcess: THandle;
  vPointer: Pointer;
  vNumberOfBytesRead: SIZE_T;
  S: string;
  vItem: TLVItem;
begin
  Result := False;

  if not Assigned(mStrings)
    then
      Exit;

  vColumnCount := ListViewColumnCount(mHandle);
  ShowMessage('There are ' + IntToStr(vColumnCount) + ' columns in this listview');

  if vColumnCount <= 0
    then
      Exit;

  vItemCount := ListView_GetItemCount(mHandle);
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(mHandle, @vProcessId);
  vProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OperaTION or PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, vProcessId);
  vPointer := VirtualAllocEx(vProcess, nil, 4096, MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  mStrings.BeginUpdate;

  try
    mStrings.Clear;
    for I := 0 to vItemCount - 1
      do
        begin
          S := '';
          for J := 0 to vColumnCount - 1
            do
              begin
                with vItem do
                  begin
                    mask := LVIF_TEXT;
                    iItem := I;
                    iSubItem := J;
                    cchTextMax := SizeOf(vBuffer);
                    pszText := Pointer(Cardinal(vPointer) + SizeOf(TLVItem));
                  end;
                WriteProcessMemory(vProcess, vPointer, @vItem, SizeOf(TLVItem), vNumberOfBytesRead);
                SendMessage(mHandle, LVM_GETITEM, I, lparam(vPointer));
                ReadProcessMemory(vProcess, Pointer(Cardinal(vPointer) + SizeOf(TLVItem)), @vBuffer[0], SizeOf(vBuffer), vNumberOfBytesRead);
                S := S + #9 + vBuffer;
              end;
          Delete(S, 1, 1);
          mStrings.Add(S);
        end;
  finally
    VirtualFreeEx(vProcess, vPointer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(vProcess);
    mStrings.EndUpdate;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

function retrieveListViewItemsFromAnotherProgram: bool;
begin
  Form1.MyMemo.Clear;
  GetListViewText(123456, Form1.MyMemo.Lines); //where 123456 is the handle of the ListView of the other program found using Microsoft Spy++
  Result := true;
end;
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this code in order to make it compatible not only with C/C++ programs but also with .NET (C# here) applications?

I have browsed forums and blogs for hours today to no avail.

All help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Robert

Comment: Have you used a window inspector to confirm that the list view in the c# app is implemented in a same/compatible way? Is it the same window class as expected, etc

Comment: Hi Caius, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my thread. I have used Microsoft Spy++ to gather the handle of the listview in the C# app in question and also its class name: WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.74db74_r6_ad1
Below this, and still in MS Spy++, a subhandle is shown as SysHeader32. This looks exactly the same as when I checked with the C++ app which works using the delphi code above.

Comment: Can you post a side by side breakdown of the spy++ windows, each looking at a list view in a c++/# app? I'm nearly certain there's some minor difference between the widow hierarchy. Show the full hierarchy if you can

Comment: Why would you do this rather than use UI Automation?

Comment: Sure thing.
Here is a screenshot of MS Spy++ showing the output of a C++ application:
http://imgur.com/a/YxDOp

And here is the screenshot of MS Spy++ showing the output of a C# application:
http://imgur.com/a/srstj

Comment: Hi David,
Thank you for taking the time to stop by and reply to my question.
I am trying to detect change of status in a specific C# application and one of the ways would be to retrieve items of a listview contained in said app and analyze the results.

Comment: Yes. So why would you opt for such hackery rather than using UI Automation?

Comment: Hi David, Can you please explain a bit more about UI Automation?
Is it something I can implement in my own application in Delphi to retrieve the data (items of a listview from a C# program)?
I am open to all suggestions and ideas. My original post was simply an idea on one way to achieve this, but if UI Automation does the trick then I would be more than happy to use it.

Comment: In addition to what @DavidHeffernan suggested regarding using UI Automation in my program, I did some research and found DelphiUIAutomation (Delphi classes that wrap the MS UIAutomation library) available at https://github.com/jhc-systems/DelphiUIAutomation which looks very promising. However, and very unfortunately, it seems that the ListView control has not been implemented yet. Would anyone know more about UI Automation and ListViews by any chance?

Comment: List views should be accessible through UI Automation

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation David, you have already provided me with a very good hint: UI Automation. I shall therefore do some more research and will advise here when I come up with a proper solution.

Comment: As for your code, do you understand it? Or did you copy it? If you don't understand it, why not? If you wrote it, why did you neglect error checking?

Comment: I do understand it but I did copy it. As for error checking, first I was trying to see if it would fit my needs before going further with it. And this is when I realized that .NET applications and especially the listview component do not communicate using the standard Windows messages, or if they do, then they do it in a way that is not detected by the piece of code shown in my original post. This code works fine for standard (native) Windows 32bit applications. However, .NET libraries use a different standard to handle events it seems.